# Yodlee REST IAV matching service

Tags: rest, yodlee

So we are trying to use Yodlee's IAV matching service to verify that a user has an account with a bank.

We have successfully logged into Yodlee with our cobrand credentials and created a user, and asked for the users routing number and account number. After we have those we have made a call getting the loginForm.

Here is where we are stuck, sometimes we can login (ask the user for their bank login and password) and bingo we get back their account info. Other times we get nothing.

Is anyone using their REST IAV API? If so what is your flow? (attached below is our current endpoint flow)

1. coblogin
2. login/register3
3. getContentServiceInfoByRoutingNumber
4. getLoginFormForContentService
   (we get hung up here)
5. getMFAResponse
6. putMFARequest
7. startVerificationWithMFA1 (Haven't gotten this to work because we don't know how to get verifiableAccount.verifiableTargetAccount.targetAccountId)

If anyone can tell us what we are missing or what calls we need to do instead that would be super great.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any solution for this so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the `getContentServiceInfoByRoutingNumber` call, but I assume in the end you get a Content Service ID which you used with `getLoginFormFromContentService`.  That said, I think you are missing the main call to create the item for this user: `addItemForContentService1`.  If that contnet service is of type MFA, then you get into the flow for `getMFAResponse` and (potentially) prompt the user and then call `putMFARequest`. Note, a content service marked MFA means it *may* ask the user additional questions. You need to call `getMFARequest` and then decide to prompt the user based on the response (and you actually need to loop back to `getMFARequest` as some MFA institutions actually ask multiple questions). Here is how you should process the return data from getMFARequest (this is a recommendation I received from a Yodlee tech support query) to decide how to proceed:

1. User has entered correct answers and there are still more questions
   available - in this case on the second getMFAResponse call you will
   get errorCode as null but the fieldInfo will not be null. So you
   need to show the user the additional questions again.
2. User has entered correct answers and there is no more MFA questions
   – In this case the getMFAResponse API will have  errorCode as 0 in
   the response XML, hence You can exit from MFA flow.
3. User has entered wrong answers/or some other error scenario  – In
   this case both errorCode and fieldInfo will have null values , so
   from here MFA flow needs to be exited and then you need to check the
   refreshInfo by polling the refresh status to know the error code.

Comment: Thank you so much! We ended up going with addTransferAccount call inbetween steps 3 and 4 and no we are stuck on the enableAccountForAggregation call because we have no idea what to send it (after step 4 and before step 5) This call is supposed to send their login information to be validated. In the documentation it asks for the userContext (CobSession Token and userSessionToken) and the itemAccountId and then the itemDetails. Our problem is they don't specify what all the itemDetails are and how they should be formatted. You would happen to have any idea about this would you?

Comment: I guess I should open a new topic for this question :/ Their documentation is killing us right now

Comment: Generally calls like `addItemForContentService` use the same name and value pairs you get back from the `getLoginForm` call. I added a comment to your other ticket which explains how we do it for `addItemForContentService1`. I hope that helps.